# scala pattern matching

Tags: scala

It seems the type of Nil is not polymorphic. How do I correct this function:

```
scala> def last[A](a:List[A]) : A =   
     | a match {                      
     |   case _ :: tail  => last(tail)
     |   case Nil => Nil[A]           
     | }                              
<console>:8: error: object Nil does not take type parameters.
     case Nil => Nil[A]
```

UPDATE:

```
scala> def last[A](a : List[A] ) : Option[A] =
     | a match {                              
     |   case head :: Nil => Some(head)       
     |   case _ :: tail => last(tail)  
     |   case Nil => None                     
     | }
```

Comment: `Some(last(tail))`? The error message you pasted does not correspond to the code you pasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Nil` is an object, not a type. So `Nil[A]` doesn't make any sense.

An empty list does not have a last element. As such invoking `last` on `Nil` should throw an error.

```
def last[A](l: List[A]): A = l match {                      
  case x :: Nil => x
  case _ :: tail => last(tail)
  case Nil => sys.error("An empty list")
}
```

Alternatively you could have `last` return an `Option[A]` as shown below:

```
def last[A](l: List[A]): Option[A] = l match {                      
  case x :: Nil => Some(x)
  case _ :: tail => last(tail)
  case Nil => None
}
```

Comment: closer...but something must be missing.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you've declared the method to return `A`:

```
def last[A](a:List[A]) : A
                        ^^^
```

and the empty list, `Nil` is not an `A`.

(And (as a side-note), as the error message says, `Nil` does not take type parameters.)

---

A better return type for a `last` function is probably `Option[A]`. Your method definition, but with `Option[A]` would look like:

```
scala> def last[A](a: List[A]): Option[A] =
     | a match {                           
     |     case x :: Nil => Some(x)        
     |     case _ :: tail => last(tail)    
     |     case Nil => None                
     | }                                   
last: [A](a: List[A])Option[A]
```

Comment: Yes, a good return type for a `last` function is probably `Option[A]`.

Comment: As a bonus, the Scala library already provides this method: `List(1,2).lastOption == Some(2)`

Answer (score 0):

When you need to tell the compiler what type `Nil` should be, you can use type ascription, like this:

```
Nil: List[A]
```

But, as aioobe pointed out, this won't solve your problem. `Nil` is an empty list, not the last element of a list.

Answer (score 0):

The object `Nil` extends `List[Nothing]`. `Nothing` is a sub-type of everything (similar as `Any` is the super-type of everything), and `List` is covariant (denoted as `List[+A]`), which means that `Nil` will fit as endpoint for every list.

However, as a result of this construction, there are situations where the compiler can't infer the correct type of an empty list, and you need to give a hint (as shown by Ben James). BTW, the same applies to the object `None` as sub-class of `Option`.